# Read excel file using PHPExcel and codeigniter resulted in blank page

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

I'm trying to read a .xlsx file using PHPExcel and the echo the results in my view, but when I run the file, the browser shows nothing but a blank page. Here is my controller:

```
class Input_data extends CI_Controller{

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->helper("url");
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->library('phpexcel');
    $this->load->library('PHPexcel/iofactory');
}

function index()
{       
    $names=array();
    $no=0;
    $inputFileType = 'Excel2007';
    $objReader = IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    $objPHPExcel  = $objReader ->load(FCPATH."/upload/Lap_Final_RLPS.xlsx");
    $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $maxRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow();
    for ($i=14; $i<=$maxRow; $i++)
    {
        $names[$no] = $objWorksheet->getCell(6, $i)->getValue();
        $no++;
    }

    $data['names'] = $names;
    $data['no'] = $no;
    $this->load->view('/teps/input_data_view',$data);
}}
```

It seems that I've got it wrong in this line:

```
$objPHPExcel  = $objReader ->load(FCPATH."/upload/Lap_Final_RLPS.xlsx");
```

because every time I deleted that line and the lines below it (until the lines necessary to load my view), I got my view showed allright, unless of course, I can't read my excel file.

Can anyone show me what's wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked the logs? Do you have error display enabled?

Comment: How do I check the logs? I added this line: `try {
$objPHPExcel=$objReader ->load (FCPATH."/upload/Lap_Final_RLPS.xlsx");
} catch(Exception $e) {
die('Error loading file :' . $e->getMessage());
}` but it resulted the same

Comment: I'm sure you have webserver logs (if using Apache, you'll often find them in `/var/log/apache2`) or CodeIgniter should have its own logs, or means of setting error/notice/warning levels and writing details to a log file

Comment: I've created log files in codeigniter (by changing its config.php file). Now this is what i get in the log file:
DEBUG - 2014-08-16 18:21:07 --> Controller Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2014-08-16 18:21:07 --> Database Driver Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2014-08-16 18:21:07 --> Helper loaded: url_helper
DEBUG - 2014-08-16 18:21:07 --> Session Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2014-08-16 18:21:07 --> Helper loaded: string_helper
DEBUG - 2014-08-16 18:21:07 --> Session routines successfully run
DEBUG - 2014-08-16 18:21:07 --> Model Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2014-08-16 18:21:07 --> Model Class Initialized

Answer (score 0):

Use this article to read data from xlsx file - 
http://websixer.wordpress.com/2014/07/02/import-data-from-excel-file-in-php-support-both-xls-or-xlsx-format/

Comment: If I were to use the code from the link, where should I place the PHPExcel folder and PHPExcel.php file? Sorry, I'm new in programming

Answer (score 0):

Enable php zip extension from Apache setting, in the `php.ini`

Answer (score 0):

> convert your Lap_Final_RLPS.xlsx file to Lap_Final_RLPS.xls and try, it will work for sure, it is working for me.
>
> OR maybe save as Lap_Final_RLPS.xls